# Destructors for automatic storage

Tags: c++, oop, destructor

I've read that when we reach the end of the scope of an automatic variable are invoked to clean up the resources.

So, do basic datatypes have destructors? or what it meant here by invoking the destructor to clean up resources is different than deleting automatic variables when their scope ends?

Answer (score 3):

Objects that have destructors will have them called when the life-time of the objects ends.

Objects that doesn't have destructors (like e.g. variables of primitive types like `int` or `float`) will still end their life-time, but there's no destructor being called (since there isn't any to call).

Answer (score 1):

Well.... they *kind of* have destructors. As an example, this code will compile (though it will technically invoke undefined behavior, as it will have the effect of destroying the `int` twice):

```cpp
using foo = int;
void main()
{
    foo i;
    i.~foo();
}
```

But note two things: (1) the `using` is necessary (C++ does not want to see `~int`), and (2) it doesn't do anything. Treating primitive types *as though* they had real, function-typed destructors is important for certain template use cases (it makes it a lot easier to implement something like `std::vector`), but primitive types don't own any resources so destroying them is a no-op.

Comment: I *think* that the destructor of `i` will be invoked again at the end of main, and so you will create UB.  You need `foo i; i.~foo(); new(&i) foo;` to be legal.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Good point. I'll edit the answer.